# call another constructor from constructor body

Tags: c++

I have an object that has different constructors. Now I want to add another constructor that based on arbitrary data will try to process that data and call the correct constructor.

AFAIK there are two ways to do it:

- static function that returns the created object

  static *A from_data(/*arbitrary data*/);
- create a private "init" function that is called by constructors

But I am wondering what are the problems and potential pitfalls of using a placement new on this using the desired constructor. So the code would be:

```
#include <new>

struct A
{
    /*different constructors*/
    A(int i) {};
    A(double d) {};

    A(/*large set of data*/)
    {
        /*large set of data gets processed and depending on the processing a different constructor gets called*/

        this->~A(); //deletes current object
        if (true) {
            new (this) A(1); //reconstructs object calling the correct constructor for the data
        } else {
            new (this) A(1.0); //reconstructs object calling the correct constructor for the data
        }

    };
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
}
```

Comment: I think the placement-new idea is not correct: an object is not considered to have its lifetime start until the constructor completes

Comment: This seems like bad design, is there a reason these are the same class? Why not just call a different `Init` function?

Comment: @M.M not sure what you mean by "lifetime start"

Comment: @Ben yeah I known that's why I am asking. It feels wrong. On the other hand it is cleaner since all constructors are "self contained".

Comment: No, no, triply no. Just say no.

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah we all know it is bad, but why?

Comment: @Mac: Maybe because of the explicit destructor calls and the uses of placement-new expressions?

Comment: @KerrekSB give me an example where the code would fail.

Comment: @Mac: If the second constructor (the placement new) has throws an exception, it will destruct the members, unwind to this big constructor, which will destruct those same members a second time, causing undefined behavior: often double deletes and heap corruption.

Comment: Seems to me that what you want is a static factory method on `A` that with the given parameters will perform logic that determines which constructor of `A` to use. This will negate the need to use the dubious funkiness both of calling the destructor (`this->~A()`) and of placement `new(this)` to call a different ctor. This is much more understandable, maintainable and standard and doesn't have any nasty potential side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a compile time decision (choice of constructor to delegate to) from run-time information (result of processing a data set).

That means that what you directly want, cannot be done.

But you can use your idea of a `static` member function that returns the created object, except that instead of `A*` it should return `A`, or else a smart pointer.

---

Re the other suggested solution,

> **”** create a private "init" function that is called by cosntructors

… that doesn't solve the stated problem, and it's a generally bad idea.

---

Re

> **”** what are the problems and potential pitfalls of using a placement new on this

Well, it's not code you can rely on. I believe it's Undefined Behavior because at the point where the object self-destroys it's not completely initialized. If it should turn out that it's technically well defined for the case at hand, it's not code that you would want to rely on. And in a setting with possible maintenance, someone stumbling on this code would have to replace it rather than wasting time trying to prove UB or not. Just Say No™ to the dark corners of the language.

Answer (score -2):

I briefly considered spending some time trying to figure out whether the shown example results in undefined behavior, or not. But I quickly decided that this is irrelevant, a waste of time, and is completely beside the point because the current C++ standard has a perfectly well-defined, clean mechanism to do exactly the same thing, and it would be more productive to focus my answer on that, instead.

I'm referring to delegating constructors, of course:

```
class A {

public:
     A(int n) {
        // whatever
     }

     A(const char *p, double z)
       : A(  /* some formula that calculates an int value goes here */ )
     {
     }
};
```

The current C++ standard specifies a well-defined way for one constructor to delegate the actual job of constructing and initializing an instance of the class by invoking a different constructor.

Note that this doesn't mean that one constructor gets to execute arbitrary code, before deciding to invoke the delegated-to constructor. The delegation must occur as the very first order of business, where you normally see the initialization section of a constructor; where you see things like the superclasses' constructors, if any.

Only after the delegated-to constructor returns, does the delegated-from constructor have an option of running more code of its own, to finish the job.

But this is just a minor inconvenience, easily addressed with just a little bit of coding:

```
class A {

public:
     A(int n) {
        // whatever
     }

     A(const char *p, double z)
       : A(figure_out_an_int_value_from_p_and_z(p, z))
     {
     }

private:

     static int figure_out_an_int_value_from_p_and_z(const char *p, double z)
     {
         int a_very_complicated_value;

         // Some complicated code that computes a_very_complicated_value.

         return a_very_complicated_value;
     }
};
```

Comment: Different constructors have different signatures. How to use delegates with that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Any constructor can delegate to any other constructor, and pass the parameters that are appropriate to the delegated-to constructor. The delegated-to constructor can even delegate to a third constructor. If you'd like more information on delegating constructors, read the relevant chapters of your C++ book, which will explain this subject fully, and better, than just a brief synopsis of an answer on stackoverflow.com

Comment: How will you delegate to an arbitrary constructor?

Comment: Define "arbitrary constructor".

Comment: Imagine you have 4 constructors with different signatures. You will call a different constructor based on the data you have. If you use delegates you already have to know what delegate to call.

Comment: Yes, you have to know what your delegate is. I would say the correct approach in this case is to have those four constructors themselves delegate to a common constructor that supports all the different ways of constructing the object. All the other constructors are simply wrappers for the main constructor. Also, a solution based on template constructors might also be used in some cases.